# hay posibilidades de que laravel rechace la conexion a la base de datos en mysql por el tipo de usuario?

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen

Estoy tratando de conectarme a una base de datos pero el usuario que me otorgaron no es global, es decir solo aplica para esa base de datos y me arroja el siguiente error...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede ser que no exista esa db para ese usuario, deberás pedirlo bien quien te lo otorgó

Comment: Debes tener creada la bd uer en phpmyadmin para que se haga la migración

Comment: Esta creada sin embargo no se puede conectar, estoy trabajando con store procedure y no reconoce la base de datos de ninguna forma, lo probe en local y funciono perfecto, sin embargo en el entorno no...